# Code skipping print() function and going straight to break

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am writing a code for a game in which the computer picks a random number from 1 to 100 and then the player has to figure out what the number is. When you guess the number, you are either told if the number is higher or lower.

When you guess the number it is supposed to print a message saying that you've guessed it and after that it is supposed to break. When you guess the number it entirely skips the print function and breaks.

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to try. I am still fairly new in programming.

Here is the code:

```
import random
num = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Guess which number I chose from 1 to 100: "))

while guess != num:
    if guess > num:
        print ("That number is too high")
        guess = int(input("Guess which number I chose from 1 to 100: "))
    elif guess < num:
        print ("That number is too low")
        guess = int(input("Guess which number I chose from 1 to 100: "))
    elif guess == num:
        print ("You guessed it! Want to play again?")
        option = input("Press Y for yes or N for no: ")
        if option.lower() == "y":
            guess = int(input("Guess which number I chose from 1 to 100: "))
        elif option.lower() == "n":
            break
        else:
            print ("Not valid")
            break
```

There are no error messages. Once you find the number, the code just breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the condition on your while loop

```
while guess != num:
```

Because you read the guess at the end of the loop, immediately after getting the guess the code will check the while condition. So when you guess correct the while condition fails and the loop exits. Since you already have a break, you can fix this by changing it to

```
while True:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It works, I changed the condition.

```
import random
num = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = int(input("Guess which number I chose from 1 to 100: "))
option = 'y'
while (option.lower() == 'y'):
    if guess > num:
        print ("That number is too high")
        guess = int(input("Guess which number I chose from 1 to 100: "))
    elif guess < num:
        print ("That number is too low")
        guess = int(input("Guess which number I chose from 1 to 100: "))
    else:
        print ("You guessed it! Want to play again?")
        option = input("Press Y for yes or N for no: ")
        if option.lower() == 'y':
            guess = int(input("Guess which number I chose from 1 to 100: "))
        elif option.lower() == 'n':
            break
        else:
            print ("Not valid")
            break
```